# Android how to start a database operation from a broadcast receiver if I cannot pass application context

Tags: android

In my app, when a Broadcast Receiver does what it does, I want to start a database operation as well, but the class that handles the database operation reqiures an instance of the DB singleton, which I usually hold in the application object, which is not accessible through the service context

Here is what happens:

This is my database handler:

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Its a good practice for DBTools to be a singleton. Do not instantiate it with "new DBTools(context)" but with
    // DBTools.getInstance(context) instead
    private static DatabaseManager sInstance;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;

    public static DatabaseManager getInstance(Context context) {

        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new DatabaseManager(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, Preferences.LOCAL_SQLITE_DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
```

In my Application Class I instatiate it this way:

```
// SQLite Database Handler
public DatabaseManager databaseManager;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    databaseManager = DatabaseManager.getInstance(this);
```

in my receiver I want to start a database operation:

```
public class PushNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //DatabaseManager databaseManager = DatabaseManager.getInstance(context); -> This didnt work when the database was closed in onDestroy of my app.
    new IncrementProgressIntoDB(context, eventId).execute();
```

and this is IncrementProgressIntoDB

```
public class IncrementProgressIntoDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

private int eventId;
private Context context;

public IncrementProgressIntoDB(Context context, int eventId) {
    this.context = context;
    this.eventId= eventId;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

    ((MyApplication) context).databaseManager.database.beginTransaction();
```

and in this last line, I get the following exception:

```
06-02 10:45:00.552: E/AndroidRuntime(7778): 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext 
cannot be cast to com.asdqwe.asd.MyApplication
```

I tried the solution from here: [Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)

but the context that I got was unable to resolve the databaseManager as a field.

Comment: start a service to do the sqlite operation

Comment: up until this moment I was only able to make my push notifications work with a receiver. I wanted to handle this problem and then start working on a service so the notifications work after a phone restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onReceive()` method of your `BroadcastReceiver`, replace:

```
new IncrementProgressIntoDB(context, eventId).execute();
```

with:

```
new IncrementProgressIntoDB((MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext(), eventId).execute();
```

Try this. It should work.

Comment: tried this and it passed the application context, but now I get a NullPointerException for the Database because it had been killed in onDestroy of the Application class

Comment: I will try instatiating it anew there